# SQLSTATE[42000]: Syntax error or access violation: 1064 You have an error in your SQL syntax — PHP — PDO

Tags: php, sql, mysql, pdo, mysql-error-1064

I've looked through all the other StackOverflow (and google) posts with the same problem, but none seemed to address my problem.

I am using PDO and PHP.

My code:

```
$vals = array(
   ':from'    => $email,
   ':to'      => $recipient,
   ':name'    => $name,
   ':subject' => $subject,
   ':message' = >$message
);
print_r($vals);
try {
   $pdo = new PDOConfig();
   $pdo->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION);
   $sql = "SELECT * FROM messages WHERE `message` LIKE :message";
   $q = $pdo->prepare($sql);
   $q->execute(array(':message' => $vals[':message']));
   $resp = $q->fetchAll();

   foreach ($resp as $row) {
      throw new Exception('Please do not post the same message twice!');
   }

   $sql = "INSERT INTO messages (from, to, name, subject, message) VALUES (:from, :to, :name, :subject, :message)";
   $q = $pdo->prepare($sql);
   $q->execute($vals);
} 
catch(PDOException $e) {
   echo $e->getMessage();
}
```

and the first print_r gives

```
Array ( [:from]    => abc@gmail.com 
        [:to]      => lala@me.com 
        [:name]    => abc 
        [:subject] => abc 
        [:message] => abc )
```

which is expected (none are null)

but it outputs the error

> SQLSTATE[42000]: Syntax error or access violation: 1064 You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'from, to, name, subject, message) VALUES ('abc@gmail.com', 'lala@me.com' at line 1

No idea how to fix this. any ideas?

Comment: I had the same problem I just added  $stmt->bindParam(1,$var_name); and my problem solved

Answer (score 140, accepted):

`from` is a keyword in SQL. You may not used it as a column name without quoting it. In MySQL, things like column names are quoted using backticks, i.e. `` `from` ``.

Personally, I wouldn't bother; I'd just rename the column.

PS. as pointed out in the comments, `to` is another SQL keyword so it needs to be quoted, too. Conveniently, the folks at drupal.org maintain a [list of reserved words in SQL](https://www.drupal.org/docs/develop/coding-standards/list-of-sql-reserved-words).

Comment: "order" is also reserved.  Doh!  Thanks for the post :-)

Comment: "UNLOCK" is also reserved (https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/keywords.html) :-) thanks, had run into this same problem.

Comment: I found this Q&A through a search for another question similar to this one. They (the OP) did tick the `from`, it's the `to` that wasn't ticked afterwards. Look at the error here they posted after their edit: `right syntax to use near 'to`, edit being http://stackoverflow.com/posts/4544051/revisions. The answer should be edited in regards to this. The OP also edited their question with the ticked `from`, and I have rolled the question back to its original state.

Comment: the reserved word link has been changed https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/keywords.html

Answer (score 42):

I've got this exact error, but in my case I was binding values for the `LIMIT` clause without specifying the type. I'm just dropping this here in case somebody gets this error for the same reason. Without specifying the type `LIMIT :limit OFFSET :offset;` resulted in `LIMIT '10' OFFSET '1';` instead of `LIMIT 10 OFFSET 1;`. What helps to correct that is the following:

```
$stmt->bindParam(':limit', intval($limit, 10), \PDO::PARAM_INT);
$stmt->bindParam(':offset', intval($offset, 10), \PDO::PARAM_INT);
```

Comment: turning off emulation [also helps](http://stackoverflow.com/tags/pdo/info)

Comment: @Your Common Sense: Why does it help? I had same limit values binding problem and turning off emulation did help :) But why?

Comment: @CoR It's explained pretty good in the wiki that he linked to. PDO treats placeholder parameters as strings by default (with emulation on). Limits become "... LIMIT '10' OFFSET '1';" and that's not what you want. If you turn emulation off MySQL handles the placeholder values according to their type.

Answer (score 2):

```
ALTER TABLE `{$installer->getTable('sales/quote_payment')}`
ADD `custom_field_one` VARCHAR( 255 ) NOT NULL,
    ADD `custom_field_two` VARCHAR( 255 ) NOT NULL;
```

Add backtick i.e. " ` " properly. Write your getTable name and column name between backtick.

Comment: thats very nice

Answer (score 1):

Same pdo error in sql query while trying to insert into database value from multidimential array:

```
$sql = "UPDATE test SET field=arr[$s][a] WHERE id = $id";
$sth = $db->prepare($sql);    
$sth->execute();
```

Extracting array `arr[$s][a]` from sql query, using instead variable containing it fixes the problem.