# How to send an email in background with CakePHP?

Tags: email, cakephp, background

That's it, how can I send an email in background with CakePHP, preferable using the out-of-the-box Email component?

EDIT: with in background I mean in another thread, or at least allowing the controller method to finish and send the response to the user. I want to run a function, return "OK" to the user and, after that, send an email.

If it's not possible, how could I do it using the PHP `mail` function? (only if it's a good approach)

Don't know if it matters, but I'm using SMTP.

Thank you in advance.

EDIT 2: I'm trying to use the `CakeEmail::deliver()` method, as I read from [the documentation](http://book.cakephp.org/2.0/en/core-utility-libraries/email.html#sending-messages-quickly) that:

> Sometimes you need a quick way to fire off an email, and you don’t necessarily want do setup a bunch of configuration ahead of time. CakeEmail::deliver() is intended for that purpose.

I'm trying this:

```
CakeEmail::deliver('myemail@mydomain.com', 'Test', 'Test',
                array('from' => 'localhost@localhost.com'), true);
```

But the mail is not actually being sent. Anyone has any hint on that method?

Comment: elaborate on `in background`. After a specific event? Fire off an email using the email component after the event completes.  Every hour? Use cron

Answer (score 4, accepted):

So "in the background" means you want to process the mail sending "out of band". This is to give the user a quick response, and to be able to process slow operations like email sending after the user has feedback (or as you say, in a separate thread).

There are a number of ways to achieve this, including:

- Workers / message queues
- Cron job

The simplest way is probably to use a cron job that fires off every 15 or 30 seconds.

My recommended approach is to look into workers and queues, and use something like [0mq](http://www.zeromq.org/) or [RabbitMQ](http://www.rabbitmq.com/) to queue the request to send an email, and process that outside the request.

If you want to do a cron job, rather than sending the email within the request the user has initiated, you would create a new model to represent your outbound email requests, and store that data into your database. Lets call this model `Message` for example.

```
CREATE TABLE `messages` (
   `id` CHAR(36) NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY,
   `to` VARCHAR(255) NOT NULL,
   `from` VARCHAR(255) NOT NULL,
   `subject` VARCHAR(255) NOT NULL,
   `body` TEXT,
   `sent` TINYINT(1) NOT NULL DEFAULT 0,
   `created` DATETIME
);
```

Create a Console that grabs the `Message` model, and does a find for "unsent" messages:

```
$messages = $this->Message->findAllBySent(0);
```

Create yourself a `send()` method to simplify things, and process all unsent messages:

```
foreach ($messages as $message) {
   if ($this->Message->send($message)) {
       // Sending was a success, update the database
       $this->Message->id = $message['Message']['id'];
       $this->Message->saveField('sent', 1, false);
   }
}
```

The implementation of the `send()` method on the `Message` model is up to you, but it would just pass the values from the passed in `$message` and shunt through to `CakeEmail` (http://api.cakephp.org/class/cake-email)

Once that is done, you can just call the console from the command line (or from your cron).

Comment: Thank you @Predominant for your response. It's a good solution, but I need the mails to be sent at the same time that the request is processed (or just after that).

Comment: I finally set this as the correct answer, since I didn't find any better solution and this can be a trick to achieve what I want. Thank you very much for your effort in your answer!

Comment: I wrote a blog post on how to do this as a simple plugin a couple years ago, http://www.stephenspeakman.co.uk/cakephp-sending-emails-in-the-background/ - can easily pop it into a project and reuse.

Comment: I suggest not using 'from' as a column name, this is because 'from' is used as a keyword. Please see: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4544051/sqlstate42000-syntax-error-or-access-violation-1064-you-have-an-error-in-you