# Can't figure out if why I get this error: SQLSTATE[42000]: Syntax error or access violation: 1064

Tags: php, mysql, sql, pdo, bindparam

I am writing a PHP+PDO function to check if the usernames and email addresses are already stored in the database. The SQL code returns an error(see bottom of post).

Similar posts recommend that I should change "reserved keywords", which I have checked and I have not used any from what I can see ([SQLSTATE[42000]: Syntax error or access violation: 1064 You have an error in your SQL syntax — PHP — PDO](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4544051/sqlstate42000-syntax-error-or-access-violation-1064-you-have-an-error-in-you)).

I tested the SQL string on phpMyAdmin and it works. the string looks as follows:

```
    SELECT COUNT(Email) FROM `contactdetails` WHERE 'Email' = 'example@example.com'
```

PHP code:

```
    <?php 
    function CheckAvailability($ValueToCheck, $FieldToCheck, $TableToCheck){

    //Database connection.
        $dbservername =   "localhost";
        $dbusername =     "root";
        $dbpassword =     "";
        $dbname =         "db";

        $db= new PDO("mysql:host=$dbservername; dbname=$dbname", $dbusername, $dbpassword);
        $db->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION); 


    //assigned 1 for value to be false
        $count=1; 

    //SQL String   
        $result = $db->prepare("SELECT COUNT(:Field) FROM :Table WHERE :Field = :Value");

    //Binding of parameters to SQL string
        $result->bindParam(":Table", $TableToCheck, \PDO::PARAM_STR);
        $result->bindParam(":Field", $FieldToCheck, \PDO::PARAM_STR);
        $result->bindParam(":Value", $ValueToCheck, \PDO::PARAM_STR);

    //String execution and data fetching
        $result->execute();
        $count = $result->fetchColumn();

    //If the result of the string returns 0 return true if 1 or more return false.   
        if($count==0){return true;}else{return false;}                 
    }?>
```

Result is as follows:

> ERROR: SQLSTATE[42000]: Syntax error or access violation: 1064 You
>   have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to
>   your MariaDB server version for the right syntax to use near
>   ''ContactDetails' WHERE 'Email' = 'example@gmail.com'' at line 1.

What am I doing wrong? Can I fix it? Is there a better way of doing this?

Comment: *"What am I doing wrong?"* - You're trying to bind a table and a column; you can't do that. See the link that the question was closed with.

Comment: dupe on http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11321491/when-to-use-single-quotes-double-quotes-and-backticks  as well. Your "string" is syntactically correct sql, but it's not LOGICALLY correct.