# Can't get my Entity using find method or api platform?

Tags: php, symfony4, api-platform.com

I am facing a weird problem, so the problem is that I created an *Entity* called Option using symfony command lines after adding my fields' name and type and so forth :

> php bin/console make:migration
>
> php bin/console doctrine:migrations:migrate

And ad I mentionned above, I am using api platform, so in order to get all my options, it will take me just to type :

> localhost/api/options

But instead of getting results, I get an error talking about something bad t=in the SQL syntax, which I am surely not responsible for because it is generated itself.

So I tried to get those options using the traditionnal symfony method *find* and again the same error, I tried to get just a signle one using findOneBy and the same, so the error is this :

> An exception occurred while executing 'SELECT t0.id AS id_1, t0.label
> AS label_2 FROM option t0 WHERE t0.id = ?' with params [53]:
>
> SQLSTATE[42000]: Syntax error or access violation: 1064 You have an
> error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your
> MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'option t0 WHERE
> t0.id = 53' at line 1

I surely don't know how to solve this, But I think that option is a reseved word but I am not sure about that.

Of course I dont think that there is any problem with code but some people ask for it even if it is unnecessary, but here is a simple code that caused the same problem in my controller :

```
$OptionManager = $this->getDoctrine()->getRepository(Option::class);
$options = $OptionManager->find(11);
```

Any help would be much appreciated

Answer (score 1, accepted):

SQLSTATE[42000]: Syntax error or access violation: 1064 is indicating that `option` is a [reserved word](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/keywords.html#keywords-5-5-detailed-O) in MySQL. [[sic]](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4544051/sqlstate42000-syntax-error-or-access-violation-1064-you-have-an-error-in-you)

In Doctrine, reserved words must be escaped with back-ticks in your entity specifications.

> Sometimes it is necessary to quote a column or table name because of
>   reserved word conflicts. Doctrine does not quote identifiers
>   automatically. [[sic]](https://www.doctrine-project.org/projects/doctrine-orm/en/2.6/reference/basic-mapping.html#quoting-reserved-words)

```
/**
 * @ORM\Entity
 * @ORM\Table(name="`option`")
 */
class Option
{
    //...
}
```

Comment: So I was right, it is a reserved word, Thanks I am getting the data now. Much appreciated.